# High stock filter data between two hours in a day

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, highcharts

Is there a way to filter data between two hours in a day? in High chart or High stock?

**Series:**

```
{  
   type:'column',
   name: 'series 1',
   data: [[1507068299999, 80], [1507068599999, 100], [1507068899999, 98], [1507093799999, 10]],
   color: 'green',
   dataGrouping:{  
      forced:true,
      groupPixelWidth:100,
      units:[  
         [  
            'hour',
            [  
               1
            ]
         ]
      ],
      approximation:'average',

   },
}
```

I have a custom hour selector where user can select from and to hour. Based on that I need to filter data in the chart

[image]

Is there a way to set from and to hour in high chart/stock config so that it will filter the data??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `setExtremes` function on x axis whenever the value in a selector is changed.

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

The advantage of this solution is that data modification isn't required - it's very fast.

Comment: Perform axis' `min` and `max` update instead of using `setExtremes` if you want to maintain the selected extremes after reset zoom button click: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6godcj9y/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `.filter()` and `Date` object.

Just filter on your `data` on the first row and compare the `hours` with your `from` and `to` variables.

```js
var data = [[1507068299999, 80], [1507068599999, 100], [1507068899999, 98], [1507093799999, 10]];

var from = 6;
var to = 7;

//Show the hours contained in your array
console.log(data.map(d => new Date(d[0]).getHours()))
 
//Filter the array depending on from and to
console.log(data.filter(d => (new Date(d[0]).getHours()) >= from && (new Date(d[0]).getHours()) <= to));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Was wondering is there a way to do this with high chart without filtering manually

Comment: Yes by filtering the charts data like I do in the serie ;)

Comment: Seems wasteful to calculate the hour twice for every date, although only testing would tell if this is actually a real-life performance concern.

Comment: You can optimize that when you get your data and add the revelant information. Custom filters on charts library are free, and developer can do it like he want in this way.